# Opening a document in text widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ms-word, docx

The example code opens a .txt file but is there a way to open a word document, preferably a .docx file?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Pmw, sys
filename = "textfile.txt"
root = Tk()            
top = Frame(root); top.pack(side='top')
text = Pmw.ScrolledText(top,
       borderframe=5, 
       vscrollmode='dynamic', 
       hscrollmode='dynamic',
       labelpos='n', 
       label_text='file %s' % filename,
       text_width=40, 
       text_height=4,
       text_wrap='none',
       )
text.pack()

text.insert('end', open(filename,'r').read())
Button(top, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack(pady=15)
root.mainloop())
```

Comment: You may be interested in [https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

No, the text widget can't display a .docx file. At the name implies, it is for displaying plain text.

Comment: could you display the word document as an image instead?

Comment: @fedoir: sure, but you have to use some other tool to convert it to an image. Tkinter doesn't know anything about .docx files.